# System workflow message not saving

Tags: system-workflow-messages

I'm trying to edit the system workflow message "Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)". When I edit it and hit save, it just reloads to a blank (new) message template. No changes are saved. The message is currently set to the default version.

I'm on Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.7.22. It's a copy of our live site, where I can indeed make edits. Is there some kind of file permission I could have missed when I duplicated the site? I have all the error and logging turned on for this site, but I don't see an error on the page or the Drupal log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Mod_security. If you run into this issue, contact your host and have them look at their logs. For some reason, our live site wasn't throwing a mod_security error, but the dev site is. They're whitelisting the issue so that we shouldn't continue to have the problem.